# updating database if variable is empty

Tags: php, sql

Im having trouble to update into a data base... I check if a variable is not empty and then i update into data base.. But only the last query seems to reach the data base correctly, how can i fix it?

```
if ($nuevocupolun8 != '' ) {
    $queryuno="UPDATE  `$email` SET lun8semanauno='si'; ";
    $queryunos=mysql_query($queryuno,$db);          
}

if ($nuevocupolun10 != '') {
    $querydos="UPDATE  `$email` SET lun10semanauno='si'; ";
    $querydoss=mysql_query($querydos,$db);
}

if ($nuevocupolun16 != '') {
    $querytres="UPDATE  `$email` SET lun16semanauno='si'; ";
    $querytress=mysql_query($querytres,$db);
}
```

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_` family of functions, they're deprecated.  Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: There is no where clause, are you sur this is what you want ?

Comment: @kevin The table has only one row so i didnt include the where clause! Should i anyway? why is it updating only the query in the last if?

Comment: Use `var_dump()` on each of the variables to check the content of them, if it really is empty. Also you should redesign your databese, I guess one table for each email and only one column is not the best solution. Create a relationship between different tables instead.

Comment: use php [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) empty function instead of using not blank condition. or do a trim of variable before you do a string comparison operation.

Comment: Ok i will try that! Anyway, if its working in one case, shouldnt be working on the 3 cases?